# Passing an array of TextInputs from child view to parent view. swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I have a parent view of AttackParameters which is calling a child view (MissileView)... I am sending MissileView three things. 2 arrays, which give the Missile view enough to create a grid based on those two arrays and the grid is a grid of text inputs, like Soduko. Then I am passing in an array of names so that is has the same number of rows and cols as the grid.

```
                ForEach(missileSelections, id:\.self) { missile in
                    if showGreeting{
                        Text(missile).padding()
                        MissileView(launchPointCount: launchPointsSelections, targetCount: targetSelections, names: [[String]](repeating: [String](repeating: "", count: targetSelections.count), count: launchPointsSelections.count)).padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    }
                }
            }
```

As you can see above I am calling the MissileView there.

```
                GridStack(rows: launchPointCount.count, columns: targetCount.count) { row, col in
                    TextField("", text: $names[row][col]).border(Color.black, width: 0.5).background(Color.white).keyboardType(.decimalPad).onChange(of: names)
```

Above is the missileView class. It has a 2d array of text inputs, but I would like to after the user puts text in the grid of text inputs to return that array back to the parent view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

to do that you need something like this:

```
struct MissileView: View {
    @Binding var launchPointCount: [String]
    @Binding var targetCount: [String]
    @Binding var names: [[String]] 
    ...
    }
```

with

```
struct AttackParametersView: View {
    ....
    @State var names = [[String]]()
    ...
    
    MissileView(launchPointCount: $launchPointsSelections,
                targetCount: $targetSelections,
                names: $names))
    
    
    }
```

and somewhere before calling "MissileView(....)" do:

```
        names = [[String]](repeating: [String](repeating: "", 
        count: targetSelections.count), 
        count: launchPointsSelections.count)
```

or put this in MissileView, something like:

```
    .onAppear(perform: {
        names = [[String]](repeating: [String](repeating: "", count: targetCount.count), count: launchPointCount.count)
    })
```

Edit:

I cannot do all your code for you, however your setup is complicated enough
that you should look into creating a dedicated model
that holds the state of your system, and use that for the inputs you want for each "grid".

An ObservableObject model that you pass around, for example:

```
class AttackParameters: ObservableObject {
    @Published var grids ....
    @Published var names ....
    ...
    
}
```

then use it in AttackParametersView, and similarly in MissileView:

```
@ObservedObject var attackParameters = AttackParameters()
```

So when your attackParameters model changes, all views will know about it and adjust accordingly.

Comment: So the only problem with this is, I have multiple grids, so when I put a input in for 1 grid, the other grid is getting the same input. So maybe I need an array of names? I am not really sure. Could you help?

Comment: yes most likely, if you have multiple "grid" and you want each to have its own "input", then an array or set or a dictionary would the way to go.

Comment: So what would need to be the array? I am sorry, I am so used to visual. Can you edit your answer?